# C++ code confusion with template method call

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

The documentation of the program API I use lacks of the required information so I tried to understand on my own how to use the `HashMap::FindOrCreateEntry()` method.

```
template <typename C> Entry* FindOrCreateEntry(const K& key, C& constructor, Bool& created)
{
    /* ... */
    Entry* e = (Entry*) _allocator.Alloc(SIZEOF(Entry), C4D_MISC_ALLOC_LOCATION);
    if (!e)
    {
        created = false;
        return nullptr;
    }
    e = constructor.ConstructHashMapEntry(e, key);
    /* ... */
    return e;
}
```

The part I am suspicious about is the second method with the same name:

```
struct DefaultEntryConstructor
{
    static Entry* ConstructHashMapEntry(void* ptr, const K& key)
    {
        return new (ptr) Entry(key);
    }
};

Entry* FindOrCreateEntry(const K& key, Bool& created)
{
    return FindOrCreateEntry(key, *(DefaultEntryConstructor*) nullptr, created); //lint !e413
}
```

1. Why are there no template parameters passed to the call of `FindOrCreateEntry()`?
2. Shouldn't this call crash? It dereferences a `nullptr`! Or at least, it should be dangerous to do it this way? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Template parameters can be deduced, and yes, dereferencing `nullptr` is bad.

Comment: This: `*(DefaultEntryConstructor*) nullptr` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1 Why are there no template parameters passed to the call of FindOrCreateEntry()?

because the compiler can deduce the types from the parameters passed. Here, `C = DefaultEntryConstructor`.

> 2 Shouldn't this call crash? It dereferences a nullptr! Or at least, it should be dangerous to do it this way? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

But `DefaultEntryConstructor::ConstructHashMapEntry` is *static*, so in the line

```
e = constructor.ConstructHashMapEntry(e, key);
```

the *value* of constructor is never used (and it doesn't matter that it is a nullptr) - only the *type* of the pointer is used to resolve the function call.

---

Let's look at that static method call in a little more detail. When the compiler instantiates

```
e = constructor.ConstructHashMapEntry(e, key);
```

it knows the type `C` of `constructor`. So, the first step is to identify the function to call. Depending on the type of this function, the call site could have one of four types:

1. a regular non-virtual method call: this will generate a regular method call with an implicit `this` parameter, so it uses the *value* of the `constructor` object reference
2. a virtual method: this will use some mechanism (typically a vtable) to look up the function pointer at run-time: both the lookup and the call rely on the *value* of the object reference or pointer
3. a static method (our case): this will generate a function call with no implicit `this` parameter. Only the *type* of the object has been used here, and the *value* is ignored completely
4. a constexpr: the runtime value of the object obviously can't affect this, so isn't used

Note that while it may seem confusing to call a static as `constructor.ConstructHashMapEntry(e, key)` instead of `C::ConstructHashMapEntry(e, key)`, this form allows `FindOrCreateEntry` to use handle both static *and* non-static methods, depending on the type of `C`.

Comment: I think the OP would be right to expect `2.` to crash if there were any data member in the struct though. I mean, maybe it is only lucky that it is optimized away by the compiler? Even if this is legal, it is certainly an odd way of doing it.

Comment: Any idea of what logic is behind such a construction?

Comment: Thank you for this great answer! Very comprehensible. :)

Comment: Expecting a crash might be a little too much, but at any rate that is undefined behavior (not the call to the function `ConstructHashMapEntry`, but the previous dereference of `nullptr`)

Comment: It's counter-intuitive that converting a pointer to a reference - without actually reading or writing through it - should count as a de-reference (and intuitively it's easy to see why it works in practice here), but IIRC you're absolutely right.